# Putting CAPTCHAs on their own page?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, captcha

We need to put a captcha image on our ASP.NET MVC 2 based website. We chose reCaptcha and built it in using the way described by [Derik Whittaker](http://devlicio.us/blogs/derik_whittaker/archive/2008/12/02/using-recaptcha-with-asp-net-mvc.aspx). The idea there is baiscally to build some abstractions and all you need to do is decorate your Controller with a `[ValidateCaptcha]` attribute. This works all fine.

However, we have a lot of form-widgets in different pages and I don't want to have the captcha floating around everywhere. So I'd like to implement it the way StackOverflow does: `Submit a Form -> Challenge Captcha -> Submit Captcha -> Perform Action on original form data`.

Now, how do I redirect the user to the captcha page while keeping the originally submitted information?

I thought of some very ugly hacks (hidden fields w/ base64 encoded form data, etc.) but I think I'm missing something obvious. On the other hand, this sounds as if I wanted to do something in a stateful manner, and I shouldn't?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Session or [persisting model state on the client](http://weblogs.asp.net/shijuvarghese/archive/2010/03/06/persisting-model-state-in-asp-net-mvc-using-html-serialize.aspx) comes to mind.

Comment: Persisting model state looks just like my hack idea, but clean, isolated and reusable. Nice. Let me check, but this looks really promising.

Comment: I went for the session in the end, but that still proved to be more tricky than I thought. Thanks for the answer.